# How to control speed of CSS transform with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list that scrolls with a CSS transform, but I want to have the same speed no matter how long the list is. How can I control the speed with jQuery?

Here is the CSS, and a link to a pen: https://codepen.io/disco_p/pen/BvWdqX?editors=1100

```
section {
    height: 90vh;
    background: #000;
}

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: em(18);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    column-count: 4;
    column-width: 200px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    animation: floatTextUp 3s infinite linear;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
  }

  .scroll {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  @keyframes floatTextUp {
    to {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is not possible with just CSS, as it only gives you the option to change the duration. What you can do, is adjust the duration, based on the length of the list (using javascript/jquery).

Answer (score -1):

Hi Elizabeth and welcome :)

You travel 100%(this is relative) in 3s. So you will need to have a fixed(absolute) height so get a constant speed.
Is there a maximum List size? If yes, you can just use this as default height and adjust your animation time until you like the speed.

You have to use some type of absolute height, so the speed is deterministic according to the pixel to travel:
`min-height: 200px;` for your `.ul`

This will work until all space is used.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPJYBe?editors=1100)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the animation duration with jquery based on the length of the list.

```
function calcDuration(length) {
   /* For every ten items take 1s */
   return length / 10 + 's';
}

const listLength =  $('ul li').length;

$('ul').css('animation-duration', calcDuration(listLength));
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? You can see it working here: https://codepen.io/knightjdr/pen/LMWmWz